# ORDER BY with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Is there a way to order your table by something that you don't select in the select clause such as:

```
Table Example

   Column  |    Type   |
-----------+-----------+
language   | character |
percentage | real      |
id         | integer   |
```

So I want to ideally do something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT language FROM Example ORDER BY percentage DESC;
```

But this obviously doesn't work. Is there a way that I can actually get it to order it by the percentage without actually selecting percentage in the SELECT clause?

This query

```
SELECT DISTINCT language 
FROM countrylanguage 
ORDER BY percentage DESC;
```

gives this error message:

> ```
> ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
> LINE 1: ...T DISTINCT language FROM countrylanguage ORDER BY percentage...
> ```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT language FROM countrylanguage ORDER BY percentage DESC;
ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...T DISTINCT language FROM countrylanguage ORDER BY percentage...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to select a column to sort on it.

```
create table language_pct (
  id integer primary key,
  language varchar(15) not null,
  percentage real not null,
  unique (language)
);

insert into language_pct values
(1, 'English', 15.3),
(2, 'French', 32.108),
(3, 'Russian', 12.88);

select language
from language_pct
order by percentage desc;

French
English
Russian
```

And if you had two rows for English, each with a different percentage, what would you have the dbms do for `select distinct...`?

Comment: Okay yea that works, I was looking at my tables wrong because I have multiple languages in my table that correspond to different countries or regions so that's why I was putting DISTINCT in there but I forgot different regions might contain the same language. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple entries per language, want only one row per language in the result, and still want to sort by a percentage, you may want to `GROUP BY language` and aggregate the percentage with `sum()` (or another [aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE), depending on your actual data):

```
SELECT language, sum(percentage) AS total_percentage
FROM   countrylanguage
GROUP  BY language
ORDER  BY total_percentage DESC;
```

If you just want *one* entry per language with the *biggest percentage*, you can use `DISTINCT ON` but to-be-distinct columns *have* to come first in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (language)
       language, percentage
FROM   countrylanguage
ORDER  BY language, percentage DESC;
```

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

To sort by language now, you would have to put that into a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   <query from above>
   ) AS sub
ORDER  BY percentage DESC, language; -- language only serves as tiebreaker
```

Or use a different route with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT language, max(percentage) AS max_percentage
FROM   countrylanguage
GROUP  BY language
ORDER  BY max_percentage DESC;
```

Or combine `DISTINCT` with [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE):

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT
          language, max(percentage) OVER (PARTITION BY language) AS max_percent
   FROM   countrylanguage
   ) AS sub
ORDER  BY max_percent DESC;
```

The last one will be slowest in this case.